# Enabling logwatch to log successful requests as well

Tags: nginx, logwatch, http-status-code

I have a very low-volume http server (Nginx) which is used by only a few users and otherwise receives some probes from hackers.

For this installation I would like the logwatch output to include successful http requests as well (i.e. 200-299), I tried to adjust the configuration of the http-module, but could not get it to include those, also searching on the internet did not yield any useful information. I tried to adjust some of the config-values, but could not get it to have any effect. I am on Ubuntu and tried to copy the http.conf to /etc/logwatch/conf/services/ before adjusting it.

So is there a way to include all accesses in the logwatch-output for http/nginx?